# When an editor field overflows, should there be a bottom margin?

Tags: text-editor, margin

When a text editor overflows, should there be a bottom margin?

With bottom margin:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD88qt.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Without bottom margin:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foErqm.png)</sup>

Comment: Maybe it's just me but the "margin" as you describe it, actually looks odd at either the top or bottom. I agree there should be at least a pixels worth of padding around the scrollable content but not having the scroll bar touch each end looks weird to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your examples are very different and answer the question by themselves.

See, you'll usually have a margin, no matter if the element is overflown or not, because you shouldn't overlap elements (see your first image as example)

Now, What you probably mean is *padding*, and in that case the answer is no, you shouldn't have a padding because you lose the visual aid that indicates the element is incomplete and the user requires an action (scroll) to see the whole element (as in your second wireframe)

Also, if you have a padding and then the text continues, how are you going to deal with it? I mean, you're talking of a variable block of text with dynamic height, so... how are you going to add padding after (say) line 5, then when the user goes to line 6, you remove that padding and add it again after line 6 and so on? While technically possible, it's quite difficult and obviously doesn't exist by default, for the simple reason that this behavior is not supposed to happen.

A close example would be this: try editing your question and see how your text area has no padding at all (but of course it has margin)

Comment: This textarea extends to the bottom of the screen, so I wondered if it is OK to not have any padding/margin at the bottom of the screen.